# Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes using typesafe activator play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I am upgrading Play Framework application from 2.2.2(application working fine with this version) to 2.4.4(Typesafe activator 1.3.7), while running the application, I am getting the following errors:
[image]

build.sbt:

```
name := """MyFirstApp"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  jdbc,
  cache,
  //anorm
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.4.0",
  "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "4.0",
  "javax.inject" % "javax.inject" % "1",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.9",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo" % "0.10.0",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.2",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5" % "test",
  "org.webjars" % "requirejs" % "2.1.1",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1200-jdbc41",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4",
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-iteratees_2.10" % "2.2.3",
  "com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.10" % "2.1.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-jdbc_2.10" % "2.2.0-RC1",
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-jdbc_2.10" % "2.4.4",
  "org.apache.flume" % "flume-ng-core" % "1.5.2",
  "org.apache.flume" % "flume-ng-sdk" % "1.5.2",
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.11.6"
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

// Compile the project before generating Eclipse files, so that generated .scala or .class files for views and routes are present
//EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile)
```

plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.4")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

// addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")

//EclipseKeys.projectFlavor := EclipseProjectFlavor.Java           // Java project. Don't expect Scala IDE
//EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.ValueSet(EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedClasses, EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedResources)  // Use .class files instead of generated .scala files for views and routes 

logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

Please help me regarding to run the application perfectly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'play-jdbc_2.10' is in there twice. Also, while you're using scala 2.11 several libs are configured as 2.10.

Comment: Also `play2-reactivemongo` is there twice.